# How do you structure physical and logical/solution folders?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

After a lot of reading and wading through finnicky solutions to this problem, it's bizarre that projects are structured in this way and yet there doesn't seem to be a straight forward way of creating it.

A brilliant example is Microsoft's eShopOnContainers project - https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers

The repository has a physical src folder, when you open the eShopOnContainers-ServicesAndWebApps.sln - the solution explorer displays the src as if it were a logical folder.

I find that the .sln also lives in a peculiar place - directly within the src folder, it's almost like this .sln has been created manually and projects added to it as necessary.

The same is the case with the Services folder and its contents, each project lives as Services/Identity/Identity.API - this full structure displays in both file explorer and solution explorer, but when I attempt to recreate this I can 1 of 2 scenarios -

1. I create the folder structure as physical folders and they do not display in the solution explorer.
2. I create the folder structure as logical/solution folders and they do not display in the file explorer.

This doesn't seem possible via the projection create GUI, I imagine this has been done by creating the projects and structure via the dotnet CLI, but I can't seem to figure it out, how is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this via the Visual Studio GUI -

Create your logical folder structure as you see fit within Visual Studio, and then to have your physical folders match that structure - or even differ from it - create the path along with the project which you are creating, the file system will create the physical folders from the specified path and you will have achieved the desired effect.

Example:

Create C:\myproject\src\

Visual Studio -> File -> New -> Project -> Blank Solution (name: myprojectsolution)

Right click myprojectsolution -> Add -> New Solution Folder (name: src)

My the myprojectsolution.sln into C:\myproject\src\ then delete the myprojectsolution folder which was created with the .sln file.

Logical and Physical folders are now matching, the .sln lives directly in src, and src will display in the solution explorer.

At this point, let's say you want to create an Identity.IDP project at Microservices\Identity\Identity.IDP, with a matching logical and physical structure.

Visual Studio -> right click src -> Add -> New Solution Folder (name: Microservices)

Visual Studio -> right click Microservices -> Add -> New Solution Folder (named: Identity)

Visual Studio -> right click Identity -> Add -> New Project (name: Identity.IDP, location: C:\myproject\src\Microservices\Identity)

The above will result in a matching folder structure existing in both the solution explorer and the file explorer.

In summary - create your solution structure via the Visual Studio GUI, create your physical structure via specifying the path when creating the project.